# Web API 2 Batch Request Routes Correctly But No Data or 500 Error

Tags: asp.net, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I recently created a new Web API 2 project and am using most of the default scaffolding for my RESTful API. I am trying to add batch support and have been using these two resources as a guide:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata.aspx

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web+API+Request+Batching

I added the route, and used the `DefaultHttpBatchHandler` provided by the framework so my `WebApiConfig.cs` looks like such:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using System.Web.Http.Batch;

namespace WebAPI_Test
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(
            routeName: "batch",
            routeTemplate: "api/$batch",
            batchHandler: new DefaultHttpBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the following controller:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPI_Test.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get(string id)
        {
        string val = String.Format("Customer: {0}", id);

        return val;
        }

    }
}
```

I can make the following HTTP request through Fiddler4 and get a successful response:

```
GET http://example.com:8010/WebAPI_Test/api/customers/abs HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: example.com:8010
```

I can also successfully hit the batch end point and get a 200 response, however, when I do, I do not get any data and my breakpoints on my controller are never hit. Using the following request:

```
POST http://example.com:8010/WebAPI_Test/api/$batch HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=abc101
Host: example.com:8010
Accept: multipart/mixed
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Content-Length: 179


--abc101
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request
GET http://example.com:8010/WebAPI_Test/api/Customers/abc HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:8010
--abc101--
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 84
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="1c950245-84e8-4c1b-8545-58e93cdd7b25"
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2016 00:09:54 GMT

--1c950245-84e8-4c1b-8545-58e93cdd7b25

--1c950245-84e8-4c1b-8545-58e93cdd7b25--
```

I noticed in both the links I referenced above that the subsequent requests use relative paths. So I modified my request body to be:

```
--abc101
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request
GET /WebAPI_Test/api/Customers/abc HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:8010
--abc101--
```

however, now I just receive a generic `500: Internal Server Error` response and none of my breakpoints are hit. I imagine the error is being thrown from one of the .NET libraries but I am not being given the stack trace.

In the first link above, the author is using Owin and self hosting. I noticed he invokes the `UseWebApi` method on his `app` object. Although I am hosting through IIS, I decided to give it a try (admittedly, running out of ideas here). In my `StartUp.cs` file, I have the following:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebAPI_Test.Startup))]

namespace WebAPI_Test
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the first batch HTTP request I mentioned above (with the full path in the request body) I get the same result: 200 but no data and the controller method is never hit.

When I try with just the relative path in the request body, I still get a 500 error but instead of the generic "An error as occurred" message I get the following:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage":"Error parsing HTTP message header byte 5 of message System.Byte[].",
  "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMessageExtensions.<ReadAsHttpRequestMessageAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Batch.DefaultHttpBatchHandler.<ParseBatchRequestsAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Batch.DefaultHttpBatchHandler.<ProcessBatchAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Batch.HttpBatchHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
}
```

I have tried to modify my Customers controller get method to run asynchronously (i.e return a `Task<IHttpActionResult>` although since all I am doing is returning a string I see how pointless that is) but I still receive the same error message.

I am hoping there is something painfully obvious that I am missing. I have not been able to find any forums/questions/resources that address this issue. If anyone has any insight or help, it would be much appreciated. If need be, I can post more of my configuration code (although it is pretty standard scaffolding). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the Inspectors tab -> Response sub tab --> JSON menu (or Raw menu) in Fiddler for the response data?

Comment: Yeah, those errors above are from the Raw menu for the response. Sorry, if that was unclear. Before I invoked the UseWebApi method, the raw response was literally "An error occurred" and the above message with the stack trace is after I called it on the app object. I originally had an HttpModule for basic authentication. When trying to step through it jumps from the context.OnAuthenticateRequest call to contect.OnEndRequest and I receive those errors messages. I am a loss as to how to further debug this (can't step into .net code) or what I may be doing wrong :/ Thanks for your response.

Comment: Sorry, i was busy and could not check this one. This morning i created the solution as you mentioned in this and i am able to get response from the Fiddler. Here is what i have done.
1. Created a WebApi2 solution and added a Controller called "BatchApi_Test" with the same "Get" method you mentioned.
2. Update webapi.config.cs to include the batch support
3. Composed a Get request in Fiddler. The exact request was,
http://localhost:17060/api/BatchApi_Test/abs22

Comment: This morning i created the solution as you mentioned and i am able to get response. Here is what i have done.
1. Created a WebApi2 solution and added a Controller called "BatchApi_Test" with the same "Get" method you mentioned.

2. Update webapi.config.cs to include the batch support and hit Start Debugging from Visual Studio

3. Composed a Get request in Fiddler. The exact request was,
http://localhost:17060/api/BatchApi_Test/abs22

4. Hit Execute.

5. Double clicked the request from the left hand and found the Json response as 
JSON=Customer: abs22

Comment: I was able to debug also... I will check the $batch shortly and will get back to you.
Please note that hostname should match your hostname (say localhost if you are debugging in your machine) and I don't suppose it can be example.com unless your server name is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with an update to IIS.

I should have updated this a while ago in case anyone else came across it; if there is anyone else out there using Windows Server 2008/Windows 2007 this was ultimately resolved with an update to IIS. I wish I could report back on what the issue initially was but once it was working, it didn't require further investigation (at least not from my then employer's point of view).